# TextView's text(gotten with httpclient) cannot be set

Tags: android

I am trying to get data from some website with the help of httpclient and then set that data to a text view but it won't happen. Here is the first class where I just set the text of the textview to the text that will be gotten from the other class

```
public class HttpExample extends Activity {
    TextView httpStuff;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.httpex);

    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    GetMethodEx obj = new GetMethodEx();
    String result;
    try {
        result = obj.getInternetData();

        httpStuff.setText(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is the class I am trying to get the data from. data from httpclient more specifically

```
public class GetMethodEx {
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI(
                    "http://www.mybringback.com/");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the xml part. I am updating the question by including the xml code before someone asks me to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTwitter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHttp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading Data" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It won't happen meaning it crashes?

Comment: No no no. It runs perfectly. The textview's text does'nt change

Comment: well you surrounded the code that sets the text with try-catch, it may have thrown an exception and you catched it: check if there is a stacktrace printed in logcat

Comment: it should crash coz you are running network operation on ui thread

Answer (score 1):

Do your network related work in `Background` using `AsyncTask` like below:

```
class AsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
BufferedReader in = null;
String data ="";
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... aurl) {
        try{


    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI(
                "http://www.mybringback.com/");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                return "Error";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
return data;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String cnt) {
            httpStuff.setText(cnt);
    }
}
```

And called like

```
new AsyncTask2().execute();
```

And do not forget to add `permission` in `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```